# How does Hibernate call sequence generators?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have next code

```
getEntityManager().persist(country.getCity().getClinic().getPatient());
```

and see next sql in log

```
Hibernate: 
select
    next value for patient_seq 
from
    dual_patient_seq
Hibernate: 
    select
        next value for clinic_seq 
    from
        dual_lclinic_seq
Hibernate: 
    select
        next value for city_seq 
    from
        dual_city_seq
```

But sequence for 'country' isn't generated. All XML are allright. Whan is the problem?

Comment: Any more information on the entities and especially the relations? Are there cascades etc. defined? Might `country` be persisted already?

Comment: Sequence is usually defined in your entity class / hbm xml's , verify if the sequence generator is defined for country .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx, Thomas! Problem was in 'cascade'. I change City.hbm.xml from

```
  <set name="countrysPersistent" lazy="true" inverse="true" >
   <key column="country" />
         <one-to-many class="Country" />
      </set>
```

to

```
<set name="countrysPersistent" lazy="true" inverse="true"  cascade="all">
    <key column="country" />
         <one-to-many class="Country" />
      </set>
```

and it was helpful!